# How to search a pattern text and transpose in a single line till the next time same text is found?

Tags: awk

I am trying to parse logfile with timestamp header in square bracket. If square bracket is found then all the lines below it will be transposed until next time same square bracket is found?
I have Data in this format:

```
[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent
Event {
recordLength 4,
recordType 0,
FileHeader {
file-format-version T,
pm-recording-version C,
pm-recording-revision R,
year 2,
month 3,
day 3,
hour 1,
minute 1,
second 8,
ne-user-label LD,
ne-logical-name LD
}
} 
[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent
Event {
recordLength 1,
recordType 3,
ScannerConnection {
hour 1,
minute 1,
second 8,
millisecond 0,
scanner-id '0'H,
status 2,
padding '0'H
}
}
and so on......The number of lines after[Date Time] LTE Event is not fixed and keeps on changing
```

I am looking for output in excel like:

```
[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent  LTEEvent {  recordLength 417    
[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent  LTEEvent {
```

Comment: @user3683441 does your input file has only such data or something unrelated too? because if there are other lines, it might affect how solution is derived

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR Most likely but I feel like abusing it (the missing comma). :D

Comment: What you're asking to do is not `transpose` text. `append` maybe...

Comment: Hi , the code doesn't work for me, may be the data I provided was inadequate, I have edited the question again with more data.

Answer (score 1):

Some more [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

**Input**

```
$ cat file
[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent
LTEEvent {
recordLength 417,
[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent
LTEEvent {
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -v RS=, '{ $1=$1 }1' file
[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent LTEEvent { recordLength 417
[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent LTEEvent {
```

**Explanation**

- `-v RS=,` Record separator is set to comma
- `$1=$1`
  When you do `$1=$1` (or any other assignment to a field) it causes record recompilation where `$0` is rebuilt with every `FS` replaced with `OFS`, so it will set output field separator(OFS) to default ( that is single space), so newline char are removed.
- `1` does default action `{ print $0 }`

**OR**

```
$ awk '/^\[/{if(s)print s;s=""}{sub(/,$/,"");s =(s ? s OFS:"") $0}END{if(s)print s}' file
[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent LTEEvent { recordLength 417
[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent LTEEvent {
```

**Explanation**

```
awk '/^\[/{                               # search for line starts with [
         if(s)print s;s=""                # if variable s has something print and reset
     }
     {
       sub(/,$/,"");                      # remove comma before the line terminator from record
       s =(s ? s OFS:"") $0               # concatenate variable s with current record
     }
  END{                                    # end block
       if(s)print s                       # if s has something print 
     }' file
```

Comment: hedge: The above command works for me, just the issue is that whenever I take the output in txt, it is as per expectation, but as soon as I give the output as csv/xls then it comes back to normal vertical format. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @user3683441: how would you expect to have output ? everything in one column ?

Comment: contents of first timestamp should come in different column but in a single row, then for next timestamp the contents should come in different column but in single and on....

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if your file doesn't have `.*`)

```
$ echo $(cat f)|sed 's/\[/\n\[/g'

[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent LTEEvent { recordLength 417,
[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent LTEEvent {
```

EDIT 1: With new input.

```
awk '{printf "%s ", $0} END {printf "\n"}' f | sed 's/\[201/\n\[201/g' |nl

     1  [2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent Event { recordLength 4, recordType 0, FileHeader { file-format-version T, pm-recording-version C, pm-recording-revision R, year 2, month 3, day 3, hour 1, minute 1, second 8, ne-user-label LD, ne-logical-name LD } }  
     2  [2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEvent Event { recordLength 1, recordType 3, ScannerConnection { hour 1, minute 1, second 8, millisecond 0, scanner-id '0'H, status 2, padding '0'H } } and so on......The number of lines after[Date Time] LTE Event is not fixed and keeps on changing
```

If you are getting expected output then replace `|nl` at the end of command.

Comment: why `echo $(cat f)` ?

Comment: That is alternative of `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf $i" "}' f` to merge all lines into one.

Comment: That will fail given various input contents. Try it if `$HOME` or `.*` exist in the input file. It's also non-portable due to use of `\n` in the sed command.

Comment: @EdMorton - Thanks for your suggestion, I have added your comments in answer and What is your recommendation in this case except for awk?

Comment: Hi Vipin, After the code , I am getting all of my logfile in a single line in continuous stream, instead of coming in different lines. However is it possible to get the output in csv so that I can analyse in Excel format?

Comment: try this command first - `awk '{printf "%s ", $0} END {printf "\n"}' file.txt | sed 's/\[201/\n\[201/g'|head -2` and see if you are getting proper output or not, above command is working fine for me.

Comment: Vipin except for awk, idk. No other approach makes sense for this. @AkshayHegde's first awk script (`awk -v RS=, '{$1=$1}1' file`) is the right approach unless there's something else about the input data that the OP hasn't shared with us.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR: With this code `awk '{printf "%s ", $0} END {printf "\n"}' file.txt | sed s/\[201/\n\[201/g'|head -2` only first line is coming as output and the size of the txt output is 1KB only. Rest of the data is not coming.

Comment: @AkshayHegde: With this code `awk -v RS=, '{$1=$1}1' file` whole output comes as a continuous lines one after the other. Require the same output in different lines whenever there is [Timestamp] in excel format.

Comment: From  above command, one line as an output was expected followed by a blank line, Now to get the completed data, use below - 
`awk '{printf "%s ", $0} END {printf "\n"}' file.txt | sed 's/\[201/\n\[201/g' > output.txt`

Comment: @user3683441: use 2nd approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278909/how-to-search-a-pattern-text-and-transpose-in-a-single-line-till-the-next-time-s/43279977#43279977) first approach is based on comma, second one is based on line starts with `[`

Comment: @AkshayHegde: 2nd Approach: `awk '/^\[/{if(s)print s;s=""}{sub(/,$/,"");s =(s ? s OFS:"") $0}END{if(s)print s}'` works for me in txt. When I am trying to take output in csv, it is coming as output one below the other.

Comment: @user3683441 - I would suggest you to use this website and upload your input and expected file and share the file link.

`https://expirebox.com/`

Comment: Done, Link is [link](https://expirebox.com/download/5e190c1e4b0536ad2afb890c780e8c4e.html)

Comment: @user3683441 - Output is here - 
https://expirebox.com/download/240fde1146d79591eef2d76013e82c2c.html

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR: I do not know why the output with same command is not coming in.xlsx format, however when I am trying to get the output in .xls or in.csv format, the row are coming one below the other instead coming in single line.

Comment: @user3683441 - A quick fix will be to get the output in `.csv` file and then open this output file with Microsoft excel or open office and Finally save it as `.xlsx` file.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR: The problem with taking output in .csv is already mentioned that data is coming vertically one after the other instead of Horizontal at each time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

Abused in awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ORS=""}{sub(/,$/,"\n")}1' file
[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEventLTEEvent {recordLength 417
[2017-03-31 01:15:08.000] LTEEventLTEEvent
```